# Sprite starts in lower left corner of screen - libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a player setup with box2d and I am trying to draw a sprite over the player. The player spawns in the middle of the screen, while the sprite spawns in the lower left hand corner of the screen but does move along with the player entity, just starting at a different location.

GameScreen snippet:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    super.render(delta);
    player.update();
    world.step(TIMESTEP, VELOCITY_ITERATIONS, POSITION_ITERATIONS); 
}

@Override
public void show() {
    player = new Player(world, 0, 0);
}
```

Player class snippet:

```
public Player(World world, float x, float y) {
    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("sprites/Player.png"));
    sprite = new Sprite(texture);
}

public void update() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    batch.begin();
    sprite.draw();
    sprite.setPosition(body.getPosition().x, body.getPosition().y);
    batch.end();
    body.setLinearVelocity(impulse);
}
```

I tried setting the position of the sprite in the constructor based on the body's coordinates but it doesn't seem to be working. I have removed body & fixture code. Any push in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with 'The player spawns in the middle of the screen'?

Comment: @ssantos I pass in 0, 0 when I instantiate the player object in my game screen class, which puts my object in the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable box2d debug render, you'll probably find that both the texture and the body are starting at the left corner of the screen. Actually, `0, 0` are supposed to be the coordinates for the left bottom corner. In order to set your body in the center of the screen, you should set something like

```
(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2) / PTM_RATIO, (SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2) / PTM_RATIO
```

as your body initial position.